# can webserver recognize webbrowser control vs internet explorer software when user load page?

Tags: c#

can webserver recognize webbrowser control vs internet explorer software when user load page ?

if i load page through webbrowser control in c# i get "500 server error"
when i do it in the internet explorer software it work o.k.

why there is diffrent behevior and how i can manage that ?

thanking in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the event log to see the reason for this 500 error? Normally a WebBrowser is just an ActiveX for Internet Explorer so there shouldn't be any differences.

Comment: Look into the server's logs to see what caused the 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like maybe it is reacting to a different cookie
value or similar. WebBrowser *is* IE (to most purposes). A 500 is at the server, but WebBrowser is the client.

You might be able to hook WebBrowser to supply a different user-agent, but by default it should appear the same.